# linkedin api update comment count null

Tags: linkedin-api

We run a daily job to pick up data from LinkedIn's api and noticed a change today in the values we receive back. They are both actually 0 but one comes back as null now and another comes in as 0 as before.

Update: Timestamp: 2017-03-28T19:31:25.281Z, UpdateKey: UPDATE-xxxxxxxx , UpdateType: CMPY
NumLikes: 1 , **UpdateComments: Total: 0**

Update: Timestamp: 2017-03-27T18:37:12Z, UpdateKey: UPDATE-xxxxy , UpdateType: CMPY
NumLikes: 0 , **UpdateComments: null**

Does LinkedIn change their data returns often? Is this something to be expected? Anyone else running into this today? I'm concerned that there may be something happening on LinkedIn's end that may cause us to receive null values when it should return something other than 0.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of an API call that produces this? Typically, questions include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Since the beginning of 2017 there are changes in the Linked In API. 
See: http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Recent-changes-in-LinkedIn-API
and https://cloud.c2m.net/linkedin/linkedin-api

Another posibility could be a rejection due to trying to access the data from an App or a desktop application, in such case, just add

```
?allowUnsupportedBrowser=true
```

to your POST request.