# Missing likes/comments in LinkedIn API response

Tags: linkedin-api

since 4 days my job which is fetching linkedIn updates is getting `null` responses for likes and comments (requests on specific updates : `/updates/key={update-key}/likes` and `/updates/key={update-key}/update-comments` endpoints). This is probably expected since when requesting on `/updates/key={update-key}`, the response does not have likes nor comments field.

**My question is how can I get those values for specific updates** (which I managed to get previously) since I can get them differently (maybe? read following)

Here's the strangest part : when I don't specify the update (request only on `/updates` endpoint), I get the following response : (modified a bit for readability/privacy)

`{
  "_count": 10,
  "_start": 0,
  "_total": 212,
  "values": [
    {
      "isCommentable": false,
      "isLikable": false,
      "isLiked": false,
      "likes": {
        "_total": 3,
        "values": [...]
      },
      "numLikes": 7,
      "timestamp": ...,
      "updateComments": {"_total": 0},
      "updateContent": {...},
      "updateKey": ...
      "updateType": ...
    },{
      "isCommentable": false,
      "isLikable": false,
      "isLiked": false,
      "likes": {
        "_total": 3,
        "values": [...]
      },
      "numLikes": 9,
      "timestamp": ...,
      "updateComments": {"_total": 0},
      "updateContent": {...},
      "updateKey": "...",
      "updateType": "..."
    }, ....`

So first, the updates have their fields `isCommentable`, `isLikable` and `isLiked` set to false, despite the fact that they have likes/comments.

Second, there is an inconsistency between the fields `likes._total` and `numLikes` (the latter one is the correct amount of likes)

Does anyone else encountered a similar problem? (well [linkedin api update comment count null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182299/linkedin-api-update-comment-count-null/)) Is it something expected or a change from LinkedIn side?
I already ask to LinkedIn help center which redirected me to StackOverflow.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: same problem for me... have you solved?

Comment: Nope and the only answer from LinkedIn Help is to look developer support (which is stack overflow...) or direct contact if you are a partner!

"We're only able to help with site and support related issues. For dev support: https://developer.linkedin.com/support  unless you're a partner, then you have a point of contact. Thanks for your understanding."
https://twitter.com/AlexisPierret/status/870169770179670016

Comment: ok, in the status update request i have: "updateComments" and "likes" with a comment. I'm working on a test environment so i don't now if we have all the comments here

Comment: I also tried with a dummy company and got `updateComments` non empty. But since the `likes` field seems sometimes wrong (max 3?), can we really trust it ...

Anyway using the `/updates` endpoints to get likes and comments for a specific update is not viable solution

Comment: yes.. only the last three comments...

Comment: same problem with the rest console: https://apigee.com/console/linkedin and also with live application... i have no more ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I retried today :

`{
  "isCommentable": true,
  "isLikable": true,
  "isLiked": false,
  "likes": {
    "_total": 9,
    "values": [
      { ...`

So definitely an issues on linkedin side, fixed for now.

Comment: Also for the number of likes/comments capped to 3, this is actually expected for the `/update` endpoint so the response is not too large ;) (but shouldn't happen when requesting on a specific update)

Answer (score -1):

Same issue.

If you get a specific company update (with comment and like)
//api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/xxxx/updates/key=yyyy?format=json

{
  "isCommentable": false,
  "isLikable": false,
  ...
}

If you get comments for a specific company update
//api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/xxxx/updates/key=yyyy/likes?format=json

Result null

If you get likes for a specific company update
//api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/xxxx/updates/key=yyyy/update-comments?format=json

Result null

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer